# Hibernate second level cache and hierarchy pattern (tree)

Tags: java, hibernate, tree, ehcache, second-level-cache

I have a second level cache issue with Hibernate (and Ehcache plugin). In database, I have declared a `parent_id` field which is a foreign key to the same table (the maximum tree depth is only of 2).

So the entities looks like this :

```
@Entity(name="Foo")
@Table(name="foo")
public class Foo implements Comparable<Foo> {
    @Id
    @Column(name="foo_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name="foo_bar_id")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="foo_bar_id", referencedColumnName="bar_id")
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
    private Bar bar;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "foo_parent_id", referencedColumnName = "foo_id")
    private Foo parentFoo;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="parentFoo")
    @OrderBy(value = "foo_id")
    private SortedSet<Foo> childFoos = new TreeSet<>();

    public Foo() {}

    public Foo(int id, Bar bar, Foo parentFoo, SortedSet<Foo> childFoos) {
        this.id = id;
        this.bar = bar;
        this.parentFoo = parentFoo;
        this.childFoos = childFoos;
    }

    public int compareTo(Foo foo) {
        // ...
    }

    // ... getters and setters here ...
}

@Entity(name="Bar")
@Table(name="bar")
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Bar implements Comparable<Bar> {
    // ...
}
```

So `Foo` isn't in the second level cache but `Bar` is. The problem is  when I retrieve a `Foo` entity that has a `Foo` parent, the parent's `Bar` entity isn't retrieved from the cache.

In addition, I made some tests :

- If I remove the childs relationship, everything is OK.
- If I mark `Foo` as cacheable, everything is OK.
- If I set `LAZY` instead of `EAGER` on the `childFoos` field it doesn't change anything when lazy loading the entities.

What am I missing here ?

Hibernate version : `4.3.2.Final`

Thanks

Comment: Can you say more about `If I remove the childs relationship, everything is OK.`? But why not mark the `Foo` as `Cacheable`. I believe unless you mark `Foo` as `Cacheable` it won't cache the associated collection/entities even though you mark the `ManyToOne bar` with `Cache` annotation.

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu If I change this bidirectional relationship into a unidirectional relationship (by removing `parentFoo` or `childFoos` it works great (`Bar` is retrieved from the cache). I don"t mark `Foo` as cacheable because this entity is not a good candidate for second level cache.